# Does Valence javascript client libary work on localhost?

Tags: javascript, desire2learn, valence

I've been experimenting with the Valence javaScript client library and the 'GettingStartedSample' download from D2L.

If the sample files are uploaded, accessed and ran from within a D2L course site the script works, however, if I try to run it from a localhost I run into a problem.  On localhost I can successfully authenticate the application however when I try to run a 'Get Versions' or 'WhoAmI' request nothing happens.

Firebug tells me the following:

- Object { readyState=0, status=0, statusText="error" }  *server.js (line 77)*
- error *server.js (line 78)*
- (an empty string) *(line 79)*

Should I be able to make a request using the javascript client library from a localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes, but you need to do some additional work.

I would advise reading up on the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) so you have some background as to why XHRs (in your case, Valence calls) between domains do not work out of the box. The easiest thing to do is to use [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) if all you are making are `GET` requests. If you need to make other requests, you will need to look into getting [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) support set up on your instance.